# Can't find the friend's id to store it to the database

Tags: php

I'm really struggling with this now for a while and can't seem to get it working. In members.php (where I show all the registered users) I have a list printed out with a link "ADD TO FRIENDS" next to each user.

I managed, for testing purposes to display each members id well (so it gets the ID) but when I click the link it directs to the friends.php where it seems the fault is in. **I don't know how to get that friend's id I clicked on IN THE friends.php file.** Please have a look!

**members.php**

```
<?php
        include 'connect.php';
        include 'header.php';

        if(isset($_SESSION['signed_in']) == false || isset($_SESSION['user_level']) != 1 )
            {
                //the user is not an admin
                echo '<br/>';
                echo 'Sorry! You have to be <a href="/signin.php"><b>logged in</b></a> to view all the <a href="signup_2.php" title="Become a registered user!"><b>registered</b></a> members.';
                echo '<br/><br/>';
            }
            else
            {
                echo '<h2>Registered users:</h2>';

                $sql    = "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY user_name ASC";
                $result = mysql_query($sql);

                $num=mysql_numrows($result);

                $i=0;
                while ($i < $num)
                {
                    //$name = mysql_result($result,$i,"user_name");
                    //$id = mysql_result($result,$i,"user_id");
                    //$picture = mysql_result($result,$i,"pic_location");

                    //?friend_id="'. $id .'
                    while($user = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                        echo $user['user_name'].'<br/><br/><a href="friends.php?user='.$user['user_id'].'">ADD TO FRIENDS</a><br/>';
                        echo $user['user_id'];
                        echo '<br/><br/>';
                    }

                    $i++;
                }

                ///////////////////////////////
                /// adding users as friends ///
                ///////////////////////////////

                //while($user = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                //echo $user['user_name'].' 
                    //<a href="addfriend.php?user='.$user['id'].'">ADD TO FRIENDS</a><br/>';


                //NOW I WANT TO MAKE A SPECIFIC "ADD AS FRIEND" LINK NEXT TO EACH USER


            }
            include 'footer.php';
?>
```

As I said I'm not sure how to get this so please have a look! Thanks!

J

**friends.php**

```
<?php
    include "connect.php";
    include "header.php";

    if(isset($_SESSION['signed_in']) == false || isset($_SESSION['user_level']) != 1 )
    {
        //the user is not an admin
    echo '<br/>';
    echo 'Sorry! You have to be <a href="/signin.php"><b>logged in</b></a> if you want to add the person as a friend!';
    echo '<br/><br/>';
    }
    else
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);

                //friend_id is the ID of the friend that is clicked on...
                //HOW DO I GET THAT ID THAT IS CLICKED ON IN THE WHILE "loop" in members.php?

                $friends = ("INSERT INTO friends SET user_id='" . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "', friend_id='".$id."', status='0'");
                $result_friends = mysql_query($friends);


                if(!$friends)
                {
                    //When you can't add this person as a friend this error will show!
                    echo 'You cannot add this user at this time. Please try again later!';
                }  
                else
                {
                    //When the friend is now added to the system!
                    echo 'Great! Now the user needs to approve before you can be friends!';
                }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your friends.php use

```
$_GET['user_id']
```

Instead of $id, $id is undefined, to get the value of id from the query string you call it using an $_GET variable like,

$_GET['name_of_query_string_value']

Comment: I guess the `$_SESSION['user_id']` holds the ID of the user visiting the page and it is set somewhere else. `$_GET['user']` is holding the ID of the friend this user wants to add.

Comment: Ok cool! I understand better but now it says Undefined index: user_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\friends.php on line 20. So how do I 'declare' that specific user_id?

Comment: @AJweb: you are spot on!! But I can't seem to get it working! :(

Comment: @NVTOnline: I just simply said $_GET['user']; and it worked! Thank you very much! :)